# jQuery click event stops working after one click

Tags: jquery, load, click, live

I have a div (#replyLoop) that the link id *lmor* pulls content into from the href element *data-posts* when it is clicked.  Works fine for the first click, but then after it does nothing.  I suspect it has something to do with the structure of the code and not the events used - both "live" and "click" have the same result, as does removing return false; and only using the data-posts element of the link and removing the href portion. (return false; to disable the link's href from firing).

I always seem to miss the most obvious things when it comes to js - and I'm wondering if that's the case here.

(tooltip-e is ensuring that the *tipsy* function gets called whenever the new content is loaded in. (tooltips))

"Live" markup -

```
$(function(){
$("#lmor").live("click",function() {
    $('#replyLoop').load($(this).attr('data-posts'), function(data) {
            $('.tooltip-e').tipsy({
            gravity: 'e',
            fade: true,
            html: true
            });
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

"Click" markup-

```
$(function(){
$("#lmor").click(function() {
    $('#replyLoop').load($(this).attr('data-posts'), function(data) {
            $('.tooltip-e').tipsy({
            gravity: 'e',
            fade: true,
            html: true
            });
        });
    return false;
    });
});
```

Any ideas on what I'm missing?

**Edit** 
I figured it out - using a combination of .live and including the "load more" in the appropriate file, I have gotten it to work.

The problem: it was being called outside of the page that was loading - so that when it was looking for a "next" page, that "next" page hadn't been pushed to the link yet because it didn't know it had been loaded.

I have also marked up the live code to use 's instead of "s.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: `.live()` is deprecated, use `.on()`

Comment: And you should not mix `("#id")` with `('#id')`, use just `'` for javascript and `"` for text.

Comment: not enough detail shown to identify problem. Post some html. Also try an alert or console.log() in click handler to see if it is firing

Comment: @AndreaTurri what do you mean by `use just ' for javascript and " for text`? :)

Comment: do you have more than 1 ".tooltip-e" element on the page?  are you sure tipsy is only working on a single element?

Comment: tipsy works regardless - obviously removing it from the load function disables it on the newly loaded content - but regardless of whether it's in the stated code or not it works.  The problem is that the load more link (the link with the data-posts content) stops working after a single call.

Comment: I mean that is more correct to write javascript code between `'` and text, strings, between `"`.

Answer (score 1):

Would be easier to answer if we wouldn't need to guess, but here is my guess: is #lmor within the html that you load into #replyLoop when it's clicked for the 1st time? I guess it is, and the problem is that $("#lmor").live is set on the DOM element #lmor, then when you load the new content then you delete that dom element and create a new one. The way to do it is:

```
$(document).on("click", "#lmor", function...);
```

this way when you create the new #lmor (when loading the new content) it also gets the event listener.

An optimized version could be:

```
$("#replyLoop").on("click", "#lmor", function...);
```

if #lmor is inside #replyLoop