# AJAX load() not executing more than once

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress, load

Transferred a website to server and now my JS file seems half-broken. When pictures are clicked AJAX is supposed to load a new page into the post box. However, I can't figure out why it only executes once and then stops working. Check it out.

http://affinity-cap.com/services/

and the JS file:

```
(function($) {
    $("#wealthpic").click(function(){
    $("#main").load("http://affinity-cap.com/wealth-management/ .post-box");
    })
    $("#portpic").click(function(){
    $("#main").load("http://affinity-cap.com/portfolio-management/ .post-box");
    })
     $("#retirepic").click(function(){
    $("#main").load("http://affinity-cap.com/retirement-consulting/  .post-box");
    })
    $(".service-pic").click(function(){
    $(".post-box").animate({
    opacity: 0.1
    }, 1500);
    })
}(jQuery));
```

Would appreciate help. Thanks.

Comment: are you sure this has nothing to do with the click event?

Comment: Assuming every control is in `#main` use [**Event Delegation**](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

Comment: It may be that your load is removing the click events from the page, do you think that is the case?  To find out replace your loads with something like alert("Fired"); then click and see if that's the case.  Also you could use "on" instead.  Here is a link to another issue that might be the same problem:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11074261/jquery-click-event-stops-working-after-one-click

Answer (score 0):

#main contains the images you are clicking on. When you reload #main, it's going to cause issues with the handlers you set on the images. You should move those images to a separate div.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following, it *should* replace your click events when "main" is reloaded:

```
(function($) {
    $("#main").on("click", "#wealthpic", function(){
        $("#main").load("http://affinity-cap.com/wealth-management/ .post-box");
    })
    $("#main").on("click", "#portpic", function(){
        $("#main").load("http://affinity-cap.com/portfolio-management/ .post-box");
    })
    $("#main").on("click","#retirepic", function(){
        $("#main").load("http://affinity-cap.com/retirement-consulting/  .post-box");
    })
    $(".service-pic").click(function(){
    $(".post-box").animate({
    opacity: 0.1
    }, 1500);
   })
}(jQuery));
```

Comment: it won't replace the click events, instead they simply will never be removed.

Answer (score 0):

make your html:

```
<div id="wealthpic" tail="wealth-management"></div>
<div id="portpic" tail="portfolio-management"></div>
<div id="retirepic" tail="retirement-consulting"></div>
```

and jquery:

```
(function($) {

    /*define variables for repeatable use, if needed elsewhere*/
    var url = 'http://affinity-cap.com/',

        main = $('#main'),

        wealthPic = $('#wealthpic'),
        portPic = $('#portpic'),
        retirePic = $('#retirepic'),

        postBoxTxt = ' .post-box',
        postBox = $(postBox),

        animationSpeed = 1500;

    /*main action*/
    wealthPic.add(portPic).add(retirePic).click(function() {
        //get html element tail attribute
        var clickedElementTail = $(this).attr('tail');

        //fade postBox out
        postBox.stop().fadeTo(animationSpeed/2, 0.1, function() {
            //change postBox content
            main.load(url+clickedElementTail+postBoxTxt, function() {
                //fade postBox in
                postBox.fadeTo(animationSpeed/2, 1);
            });
        });

    });
}(jQuery));
```

and let me know ;)